# How to add a AJAX submit form inside a notification without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, toastr

I am using the jQuery plugin for notifications `toastr` js (http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/) and I am trying to add a contact form in the notification balloon and when submitted to use AJAX.
Even though that the form is working outside the `toastr.info('')` I can not make it happen in the script. when I click the submit, it refreshes the page.

How can i fix this ?

**Ajax Script**

```
$(function(){
    $("#contactform").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post('mailme.php', $("#contactform").serialize(), function(data) {

        });
    });
});
```

**HTML Form**

```
<form id="contactform" method="post" name="myform">
    <input name="phone" type="text"><input id="submit" name="Submit" type="submit" value="send">
</form>


toastr.info('I put the above HTML code in here')
```

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/e0k6e0vc/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try unbinding submit at the end as below:

```
$("#contactform").on('submit',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post('mailme.php', $("#contactform").serialize(), function(data) {

    });
    $("#contactform").unbind('submit');
    return false;
});
```

**UPDATE**

Ok.. Since the form was dynamically getting added it wasn't identifying the submit event and hence below approach will do the work:

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/e0k6e0vc/5/)**

```
$(document).on('submit',"#contactform",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post('mailme.php', $("#contactform").serialize(), function(data) {

    });
    $("#contactform").unbind('submit');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Hello, I tried it without luck. I put it in a fiddle here to be honest, maybe it is more helpful http://jsfiddle.net/e0k6e0vc/

Comment: `toastr` isnt staying for much long time!! Can you update it!!

Comment: fiddle will not be much helpful here!!

Comment: I think when the toastr.info is in the document ready, it works. But I don't want it in a document ready function

Comment: Great thanks! how can I post this with jsonp (to another domain) ?

Comment: `$.post('mailme.php', $("#contactform").serialize(), function(data) { },"jsonp");` Need to add an extra `dataType` with your post!! Please cross verify this once as am not 100% sure about the way of adding.. :)